# unbound method comment() must be called with GetPostView instance as first argument (got WSGIRequest instance instead)

Tags: django, forms, submit

I am facing this error when trying to submit a commentary in the form I've created.

This is the class view with the `CommentForm`and a method returning a `HttpResponseRedirect` for testing purposes only:

```
class GetPostView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'blog/post.html'

    def get(self, request, id):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'post': Post.objects.get(pk = id),
            'comments': Comment.objects.filter(post = id),
            'form': CommentForm()
        })

    def comment(self, request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```

In here, the `urls.py`:

```
app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name = 'index'),
    url(r'^categories/$', views.CategoriesView.as_view(), name = 'categories'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.GetPostView.as_view(), name = 'post'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/comment$', views.GetPostView.comment)
]
```

And, as in the title, when I submit the form, the error appears:

> unbound method comment() must be called with GetPostView instance as first argument (got WSGIRequest instance instead)

I'm new at Django, and I couldn't find any other situation alike mine to help me.

## **Solution**

I will put the solution in my question, because Daniel deserves the credit and points. Following his answer, I solved it by doing this:

```
"""
GetPostView
"""
class GetPostView(TemplateView):
    """
    Render the view for a specific post and lists its comments
    """
    template_name = 'blog/post.html'

    def get(self, request, id):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'post': Post.objects.get(pk = id),
            'comments': Comment.objects.filter(post = id).order_by('-created_at'),
            'form': CommentForm()
    })

def write_comment(request, post_id):
    """
    Write a new comment to a post
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        post = Post.objects.get(pk = post_id)
        post.n_comments += 1
        post.save()

        comment = Comment()
        comment.comment = request.POST['comment']
        comment.created_at = timezone.now()
        comment.modified_at = timezone.now()
        comment.post_id = post_id
        comment.user_id = 2
        comment.save()
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    return redirect(reverse('blog:post', args = (post_id,)))
```

And the the new `url`:

```
app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name = 'index'),
    url(r'^categories/$', views.CategoriesView.as_view(), name = 'categories'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.GetPostView.as_view(), name = 'post'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/comment$', views.write_comment)
]
```

Although there are many things to do to make it perfect, like only allowing comments when there's an user logged in, this is a good start.

Comment: Could you give the rest of the traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class-based views don't work like that; the url needs to point to the class itself as returned from `as_view`, they automatically dispatch to the get or post methods, and you can't route to an arbitrary method at all.

Define a separate function or class for your `comment` view.

Comment: Could you give me an example based on my code, please?

Comment: I told you what to do: take `comment` out of the class and make it a separate function. There's no reason for it to be in the class anyway, it doesn't rely on anything there (although I don't understand what you want it to do; currently it redirects back to itself, which will just cause an endless loop).

Comment: I updated my question with the solution based on your answer.